# Finding a generalized eigenvector from a zero matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the eigenvectors of the following matrix A and given an eigenvalue of -1 with an algebraic multiplicity of 3.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & -1 \\
        -1 & 2 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
 The formula I am using is $e^{tA} = e^{\lambda t(A- \lambda I)}$. I was able to find the first eigenvector and the first generalized eigenvector just fine,
$\vec{v_1} =e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $
and 
$\vec{v_2} = e^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}
        1-t \\
        1 \\
        t \\
        \end{bmatrix} $
 however, I encountered a problem. $(A- \lambda I)^3 $ is equal to

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
So the series truncates before I am able to find the 2nd generalized eigenvector and I am uncertain how to proceed. Do I find the nullspace of the zero matrix then pick a basis vector that isn't a multiple of the previous two?

Comment: Your generalized eigenvectors are of the form $s\cdot\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr 0\cr} + t\cdot\pmatrix{-1\cr 0\cr 1\cr}$; that means you have more than one linearly independent eigenvector. So you won't get any more vectors by looking at the null space of $(A-\lambda I)^3$.

Comment: So my last vector is a linear combination of the first two?

Comment: You get two different (linearly independent) generalized eigenvectors.